# Assist me understand ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am working on iOS Address Book but having some issues, I am referring the [iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1) which says

> Prompting the User to Choose a Person Record:
>   The ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class allows users to browse their
>   list of contacts and select a person and, at your option, one of that
>   person’s properties. To use a people picker, do the following:
>
> - Create and initialize an instance of the class.
> - Set the delegate, which must adopt the ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate protocol.
> - Optionally, set displayedProperties to the array of properties you want displayed. The relevant constants are defined as integers; wrap
>     them in an NSNumber object using the numberWithInt: method to get an
>     object that can be put in an array.
> - Present the people picker as a modal view controller using the presentModalViewController:animated: method. It is recommended that
>     you present it using animation.

Point one says *Create and initialize an instance of the class*, its init methods includes withnibname other property is inputview, can this be used to customize address book gui?

point three is also pointing towards *displayedProperties*, address book gui can be modified?

> Like whatsapp, viber, etc .. I also want to customize the address book
>   so I can also display status under contacts name, so I can display
>   custom image as accessories etc etc. Please check the screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are not using the build in ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Class.

They fethc all the users from the address book and populate it into a table view.
I don't know of any way to customize the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Class.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have observed few things which feels like they are using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, like search bar searching and color fading is same, first name last name sorting and according to it bold the first or last name etc ...

Comment: Hey, All the things you said can be achieved easily with a simple table view. I can not say I am sure 100000000% that they don't use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController but I am 99.9999% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply and help :)